# jQuery parent element inner HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am getting inner HTML of element by next way:

```
$(this).context.innerHTML
```

Then I am getting parent inner HTML:

```
$(this).parent().context.innerHTML
```

But this code returns same values.
Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the contents of an element, then the contents of it's parent the jQuery markup would be

```
$(this).html();
```

and

```
$(this).parent().html();
```

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 1):

The context for both queries are the same, which in this case is the element that `this` represents. When you call `parent()` the context does not change. It is still the element that `this` represents.

You can specify the context of a query like this:

```
$("...", contextElement)
```

For more information visit:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1 and
- http://api.jquery.com/context/